# Export .dae (collada) file from Google Sketchup

Tags: 3d, ibooks, collada, sketchup

Hi I have a simple ( but extremely annoying ) problem. I want to put a model into iBooks Author and im using sketchup to do it. When I export a model out of Sketchup as .dae the camera looks perfect in sketchup but when it comes out its upside down and back to front etc. I can rotate the object and change the output but it just seems so unexact...

How do I set the camera/object so that how I see the model on the screen is exactly the orientation it comes out?

Comment: Bump (sorry but I can't figure this out)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with whatever reads the DAE. When I have exported to DAE the camera has come in correctly in the applications I have tried with. (3dsMax, Blender etc.)

Check if there are differences in the way the camera is set up, Perspective vs Parallel, 2pt Perspective etc...

If you post some sample code of how you get up the Camera object then it might be possible to see if there's anything going on on the SketchUp side. But as long as it looks OK in SketchUp it's likely to be an issue on the reading application. Even though Collada is a open format different applications still interpret them differently. Some even extend with custom data that other applications with choke on.

Also, in SU8 M1 or M2 the Collada support was improved, you might want to make sure you're using the latest update.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with Sketch Up Pro and Ibooks. I tried all the camera set up but without success. The only ugly work around I found so far was to group the elements in the model and then Flip Along -> Group's Blue. Still not nice but at least not upside down.